# Microphone and headphones not working on a Toshiba Satellite L645D

Tags: microphone, headphones

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 on my computer. First I installed 10.10, then upgraded to 11.04 due to problems with the 11.04 ISO.

My Sound Card is a  **Conexant SmartAudio HD**

Now my headphones and microphone won't work.

How can I get them working again?

Comment: Go to the Sound preferances and check that Audio Duplex, is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Play around with the sound settings profile - I had to try nearly all of them to get it working:

[image]

Comment: it doesn't matter anymore, now when I boot Ubuntu I get "Fixing Recursive Error but reboot is needed! I'm gonna get a new computer